# How do I call a function defined inside controller.js from a modal popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here is my modal popup I have used in my controller.js . I just want to call a function send() defined in same controller on button click. But the ng-click is not working in modalpopup.

```
$scope.sendMessage = function(order_id) { 
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            template: '<div id="order-flow-modal" class="inmodal">' +
                    '<div class="modal-header">' +
                    '<h4 class="modal-title">Order Description</h4>' +
                    '<small class="font-bold"></div>' +
                    '<div class="modal-body"><textarea name="message" ng-model="formData.message"  style="width:100%;"></textarea></div><div style="clear:both;"><input type="text" ng-model="formData.order_id" value="'+order_id+'"></div>' +
                    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                    '<a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="send()">Send</a>' +
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-white" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>',
            windowClass: "animated flipInY",
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            backdrop: true
        });
        modalInstance.opened.then(function() {

        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function() {

        }, function() {

        });
        return false;
    };
```

And below is my send().

```
$scope.send = function() { 
        alert('hi');
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: Is the controller you specify in the modal popup, the same controller you're writing this code in? If so, won't this.send() work?

Comment: No its a different controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide your function to modal controller via  resolve config param.

Or you can provide existing scope with defined send function to modal.

```
$uibModal.open({
...
    scope: $scope
...
})
```

Comment: Can you please provide some example.

Answer (score 0):

You  can use `broadcast` and `on` event  emmitters here.

Broadcast from your `ModalInstanceCtrl` and listen it in your current controller.

Your current controller,

```
  allControllers.controller('myController', ['$scope','$rootScope',
    function($scope,$rootScope) {
        $scope.sendMessage = function(order_id) { 
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    template: '<div id="order-flow-modal" class="inmodal">' +
                            '<div class="modal-header">' +
                            '<h4 class="modal-title">Order Description</h4>' +
                            '<small class="font-bold"></div>' +
                            '<div class="modal-body"><textarea name="message" ng-model="formData.message"  style="width:100%;"></textarea></div><div style="clear:both;"><input type="text" ng-model="formData.order_id" value="'+order_id+'"></div>' +
                            '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="send()">Send</a>' +
                            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-white" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>',
                    windowClass: "animated flipInY",
                    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
                    backdrop: true
                });
                modalInstance.opened.then(function() {

                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function() {

                }, function() {

                });
                return false;
        };

        $scope.$on('send_called', function(event, args) {

        alert('Hi')

        });
     }])
```

ModalInstanceCtrl:

```
allControllers.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope',
    function($scope,$rootScope) {

    $scope.send = function() { 
        $rootScope.$broadcast('send_called');
        return false;
    };
    }])
```

If you broadcast after send method is called, you can receive in the current controller

[Refer this link](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)